# Laravel Eloquent get relation field

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have a need to get a field from the relation from within the eloquent object.

I am using datatables to pass the eloquent object across for viewing.

I have an Model called Offices and a Model called Regions

Offices
id
name
region -> belongsto regions

Regions
id
name

I need to get something like this:
Offices.id, Offices.name, Regions.name

I have tried the below but that fails, how would I get the regions name in the get method?

```
$ReportData = Offices::with('region')->get(['id', 'name', 'region.name']);
return datatables()->eloquent($ReportData)
```

Comment: Probably gonna want to do `Offices::join("regions", ...)->select("offices.id", "offices.name", "regions.name AS region_name")->get();` (fill in the logic for the join though); otherwise you'll have to do `$office->region->name` wherever you're using `$reportData`.

Comment: @TimLewis never used join how would that work?

Comment: @TimLewis this has worked, post as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To limit your query results to specific columns, and include that of a relationship, you can use `->join()`, coupled with `->select()`:

```
$reportData = Offices::join("regions", "offices.region_id", "=", "regions.id")
->select("offices.id", "offices.name", "regions.name AS region_name")
->get();
```

Note: Had to guess on the `join` logic; could be inverse (`regions.office_id`, etc)

Then, when accessing the contents of `$reportData`, you will only have access to three columns:

```
foreach($reportData AS $data){
  $data->id;
  $data->name;
  $data->region_name;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Eloquent relationships don't use joins, so you aren't able to select them in the Offices query.

```
$ReportData = Offices::with('region')->get(['id', 'name']);
```

Will execute a separate query to eager load all of the regions while allowing you to access each item's related region as a property:

```
$ReportData[0]->region->name
```

You can flatten this, use a map, or use a query with a join like Tim suggested if you desire.

You are able to limit the region data selected from the database by using a closure on with:

```
$ReportData = Offices::with(['region' => function($q) {
    $q->select('name');
}])->get(['id', 'name']);
```

However, in most cases, I would consider this as over-optimization unless the region has a lot of data in other columns.

Comment: This works but it's missing a `]` after the `}`

Answer (score 1):

Since this is rated first on google and this is what I got when I ran this search, I think it should also contain the Laravel 8 answer.
From [the Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns)

You can specify columns when eager loading relationships like so:

```
$ReportData = Offices::with('region:id, name')->get(['id', 'name']);
```

Mind you, you should always include the id and foreign id columns in this specifications, otherwise it won't work.

So it should actually look something like this:

```
    $ReportData = Offices::with('region:id, name, office_id')->get(['id', 'name']);
```

Or whatever corresponds to your specific relationship.

Hopefully you find this useful, ye brave Laravel developer stumbling upon this!